# How to search if a username exist in the given firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
 users:
  {
    apple:
     {
       username :  apple
       email    :  apple@xy.com
       uid      :  tyutyutyu
     }
    mango:
     {
       username :  mango
       email    :  mango@xy.com
       uid      :  erererer
     }
  }
}
```

This is what I am doing
CREATING USER if checkUsername method returns 0

```
 if(checkFirebaseForUsername(username)==0) {

                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"inside",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        User newUser = new User();
                                        newUser.setUserId(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                        newUser.setUsername(username);
                                        newUser.setEmailId(email);

                                        try{
                                            mRef.child("users").child(username).setValue(newUser);
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e){
                                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"error while inserting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                                        builder.setTitle(R.string.signup_success)
                                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.login_button_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                        finish();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                        dialog.show();
                                    } else {
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                                        builder.setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                        dialog.show();
                                    }
}
```

My checkUsername method -

```
public int checkFirebaseForUsername(String passedUsername){
    final int[] flag = {0};
    final String myPassedUsername = passedUsername;
    Log.e("tag","working now");
    //flag[0]=1;

    DatabaseReference mTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

       mTest.child("users").child(passedUsername).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e("tag","checking");

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.e("tag","exists");
                flag[0]=1;
               }
         }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){

         }
});




    if(flag[0]==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This is how I am inserting users in my **firebase-database** and I want to check if a username is available for a new user or not.

Therefore I need to check is there any user already registered with that username....Please help I have already tried whatever I could understand after reffering to documentation provided on the official firebase blog but all in vain!!

Comment: refer this link https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949 @Shubham Chauhan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: New answer, old one still below.

I would get rid of your method `"checkFirebaseForUsername"` because it will always return 0, no matter what.

What you need to do is this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("users").child("username").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
      // use "username" already exists
      // Let the user know he needs to pick another username.
    } else {
      // User does not exist. NOW call createUserWithEmailAndPassword
      mAuth.createUserWithPassword(...);
      // Your previous code here.

    }                               
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

Old Answer:

```
{
 users:
  {
    apple[X]:
     {
       username :  apple[Y]
       email    :  apple@xy.com
       uid      :  tyutyutyu
     }
    mango:
     {
       username :  mango
       email    :  mango@xy.com
       uid      :  erererer
     }
  }
}
```

If for example, the node apple[X] will always have the same name as the child property "username":apple[Y], then it is as simple as this.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("users").child("username").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
      // use "username" already exists
    } else {
      // "username" does not exist yet.
    }                               
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

however, if say, the node apple[X] can have a different value than the property apple[Y], and you want to see if any node exists where the "username" property is the same, then you will need to do a query.

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo("usernameToCheckIfExists");
 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
            // 1 or more users exist which have the username property "usernameToCheckIfExists"
         }
       }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
  });
```

Comment: Linxy's answer didn't work for me until I changed `dataSnapshot.exists()` to
`dataSnapshot.hasChild("the username you want to search for")`.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this.

```
                final String userName = unameEditText.getText().toString();
                databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(userName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                        new ValueEventListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "dataSnapshot value = " + dataSnapshot.getValue());

                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                                    // User Exists
                                    // Do your stuff here if user already exists
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already exists. Please try other username.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } else {

                                    // User Not Yet Exists
                                    // Do your stuff here if user not yet exists
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

                            }
                        }

                );
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just check if user is already exits or not by below code:

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    // ...
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    final String userName = "your_user_name"; // replace with your user name
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                   // User Exists
                   // Do your stuff here if user already exits
                 }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```

You can also see Firebase doc for the same on below link:

[Read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#read_data_once)

Comment: Is the "once" method still supported after the new update to the firebase?                                                                                                      And why use "uid" i only want to use the username to find the user!

Comment: Yes it is supported.It is latest code snippets from as Firebase doc.You can able to see doc updated date at the bottom of page. And you can also use `username` instead of `userId`.I just updated my answer as per answer requirement.Thanks for pointing.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.... I have updated the question please have a look and help!!