# firebase onDataChange can provide null parameter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I've one app recently launched on google play and i'm trying to fix the crashes i get on google console but there is one that i'm not able to reproduce or identificate the source:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at a.b.c.activity.MainActivity$7.run (MainActivity.java)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

It doesn't happen very often and i can't really identificate the cause but i believe is related to firebase events

I've this method:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR.execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            for (DataSnapshot reports : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                try {
                                String type = reports.child("type").getValue(String.class);
                                if (type.equals("user"))
                                    facade.reportUser(reports.child("id").getValue(Long.class));
                                else if (type.equals("comment"))
                                    facade.reportComment(reports.child("media_id").getValue(String.class), reports.child("id").getValue(Long.class));
                                else if (type.equals("media"))
                                    facade.reportMedia(reports.child("id").getValue(String.class));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                break;

                            }
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

I've similar methods running in different circunstances on `MainActivity` but each of them is trigged by firebase (`MainActivity` has no annonymous class implementing `Runnable` that is not serving firebase)

The point is what may cause `nullpointer` on it?

As you see my inner calls are all enclosed in `catch(Exception e)` so if my api fails (for any reason) it would just stop the loop, but wouldn't crash the app if would i believe the stacktrace would show other method calls.

So if i am right the only things that may be null at this code are `dataSnapshot` provided from firebase and `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`

I'm very rookie in this firebase api, is it possible they are null?
do i need to check everytime if `report.child('something')` is null?

Comment: You can find answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053248/how-to-search-if-a-username-exist-in-the-given-firebase-database) you need to use dataSnapshot.exists()

Comment: At which line of code are you getting `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @AlexMamo, the stack comes from a report of google console... as the original apk is obfuscated i cant get the real line where it happens... and as i couldn't reproduce the problem in my system i dont know exaclty which line is

Comment: If you cannot provide us the line where you are getting that error, I'm affraid you cannot get much of a help.

Comment: @AlexMamo, it is not my choice, i can't provide an information I dont have... but if you read carefully my question you are going to understand that i dont want to know how to solve it... i can do simple checks for null values or enclose in catch(nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 0):

May be @NonNull is not fully reliable, it won't prevent passing a null.

just include your code in below condition to prevent `datasnapshot` `nullpointer` error

```
if(dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.exists()){
  // write your asyntask code block here
}
```

Comment: @RafaelLima, ok i have updated the answer, Please check.

Comment: just to be clear, it isn't the answer i'm looking for