# How write user data to firebase database only once?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write the user's data to the database only when it first logs on. I don't want it to be written over and over. I wrote a method for this, but I had a problem because there was more than one value in the for loop. How can I solve this problem?

```
public void writeFirebase() {
    final Users users = new Users();
    final List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    myRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                arrayList.add(ds.getKey());

            }

            if (arrayList.size() > 0){
                for (String cur : arrayList) {
                    if (cur.matches(mUser.getUid())) {

                    } else {
                        Log.e("preee",""+cur);
                        if (mUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                            users.setUserProfilPic(mUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());
                        }
                        if (mUser.getDisplayName() != null) {
                            users.setUserName(mUser.getDisplayName());
                        }
                        users.setUserId(mUser.getUid());
                        users.setUserPremium(false);
                        users.setUserPremiumDate("free");
                        users.setUserEmail(mUser.getEmail());

                        myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).setValue(users);
                    }
                }
            }else {
                users.setUserId(mUser.getUid());
                users.setUserPremium(false);
                users.setUserEmail(mUser.getEmail());
                users.setUserName(mUser.getDisplayName());
                users.setUserProfilPic(mUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());
                users.setUserPremiumDate("free");
                myRef.child("Users").child(mUser.getUid()).setValue(users);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you explain more. do you mean that because user has multiple fields to fill, it may need to update database frequently to make it full( each time user just fill just some of fields)?

Comment: Only 2 data of the User class are being updated. Other data is written only 1 time.Of course, all the data in this code is written when the activity is called. But I don't want that.My goal is this If user data is written to the database 1 time, never write again.

Comment: do you mean each user can be created just once and never again? if so why you dont check username for existence

Comment: of course this is exactly what I want write only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to write your user data in database once and prevent from writing again you just need to check if that user is already in your database. (in this answer i consider your concern is your user existence, it can be anything else for example maybe your don't want to let user update his email address if he already entered once. so you just check that if user has entered email before or not.)
for my example(user existence) i provide some links which help you check if user is already in your database.

[How to search if a username exist in the given firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053248/how-to-search-if-a-username-exist-in-the-given-firebase-database)

[How to search if a username exist in the given firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053248/how-to-search-if-a-username-exist-in-the-given-firebase-database)

[How to check if a value exists in firebase database - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959582/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-firebase-database-android)

just seach and find if your user is already in your database or not. check this ifs before any operation. if he was't you will allow him to continue.

Comment: Thank you did not know the exist() method :) That's how I solved my problem.

Comment: i'm glad that it helped you :)